# Bing maps transaction counts with asp.net postbacks

Tags: asp.net, bing-maps

See: [Bing Maps Transactions by API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff859477.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

I'm using the bing maps web control on an asp.net web forms page. Regarding the life time of a session, this says that it will end when the user moves to a different page. What about post backs to the same page or callbacks via an UpdatePanel?

What I'm trying to do is allow the user to select a different address with some searching criteria (for example, based on a list of employees) and then show the map to their location after the postback. Obviously we want to incur as few transaction counts as possible. Initially this page was developed with a search page and then a results page. I believe that redeveloping it with a single search/results page will reduce the number of transactions. Any insight into this before I do the job will be helpful!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A postback will cause the page to be refreshed entirely. This will cause the map to be reloaded. It sounds from the Bing documentation you linked to  like that would probably start a new session.

I would think you can easily prove/disprove that with a quick proof-of-concept page, and watch your usage stats closely, and/or try to monitor what the browser is sending to bing and see what the session ID is.

If you can replace your postbacks with ajax requests, then this would entirely avoid the problem, because the page (and thus the map control) would not be refreshed as often. This would imply a single search/results page as you suggested, but using ajax requests is really the key to it. An UpdatePanel is essentially a wrapper round ajax. If you could design is so that the map control is not part of the updatepanel (and thus should not get refreshed along with it) then that might also be viable instead of standard ajax.